# What word am I? Rebus

Tags: rebus

$\space\space\space\space\space\space J\space\space\space\space\space\space K\\\space10\space\space \space\space Q\space\space\space\space\space A$

What word am I thinking of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question comes from the words used.

> Hijacking ->
> High-Jack-King